# Can I legally land an airplane in in Badwater Basin, CA?

Tags: landing, usa

Would it be legal to land a light plane in [the Badwater Basin salt flats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badwater_Basin) in [Death Valley National Park](https://www.nps.gov/deva/index.htm)?

Let me add that you can obviously land in the park, as you have runways at both Furnace Creek and Stovepipe Wells. So another way of asking is simply: do you have to have an official runway to land? Obviously, you would need to stay >= 500 feet from people, but people don't typically wander too far from the parking lot and that's a big area. Staying away from people wouldn't be too difficult, especially in July or August when there's basically no one in Death Valley.

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/45218/62)

Comment: How far is Badwater Basin from Furnace Creek and Stovepipe Wells? I don't see it called out on a sectional at Skyvector.com.

Comment: Badwater Basin is about 14 miles south of Furnace Creek, although I think it stretches north/south for several miles. It's a big salt flat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://www.nps.gov/deva/learn/management/rules-and-regulations.htm says you would have to have special permission.

> 36 CFR §2.17 – AIRCRAFT and AIR DELIVERY
>
> - (a)(1) The use of aircraft on lands or waters within the park other than at locations designated by special regulations is prohibited.
>     Death Valley’s special regulations at 36 CFR 7.26(e) authorizes the
>     use of aircraft only at the following locations:
>
>   - Death Valley Airport, latitude N 36°27’50”, longitude W 116°52’50”, commonly known as the Furnace Creek Airport.
>   - Stovepipe Wells Airport, latitude N 36°36’15”, longitude W 117°09’30”.
>   - The Saline Valley Warm Springs Airfield, latitude N 36° 48.41”, longitude W 117° 46.90”, commonly known as the Chicken Strip, is open
>       pending special regulation.
>
> *The landing of aircraft at locations other than those listed above,
>   such as for wildlife research, is permitted only under conditions of a
>   permit issued by the superintendent.*
>
> *Aircraft have a significant potential for impacting park resources and
>   human safety. By requiring permits for these activities, the
>   superintendent can manage these activities and mitigate negative
>   impacts.*

Comment: "Aircraft have a significant potential for impacting park resources and human safety." The superintendent doesn't want you to crash your plane into stuff.